# Jenkins pipeline with arithmetic operation

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

How to implement subtraction in jenkins pipeline. Please suggest me on the below,
I am not able to come up with exact solution

```
                Curr_Version=17.04
                Default_Version_diff=0.02
                Prev_Version = ${Curr_Version}-${Default_Version_diff}
                echo "previous: ${Prev_Version}"
```

Comment: Could you try `Prev_Version = Curr_Version - Default_Version_diff`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard i tried the same. it gives the Prev_Version as 17.04. not able to get the output as required

Comment: Ok, I think you need to cast these values as `float` before assigning them to the variables.

Comment: Thanks @MattSchuchard It's working fine with float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need it as a string? Then you could do

```
Prev_Version = "${Float.parseFloat(Curr_Version) - Float.parseFloat(Default_Version_diff)}"
```

Comment: @hakamariri This is not working. but its working when i substitue exact value of the same like Prev_Version = "${17.04 - 0.02}"